# Constructing a set with measure $\alpha $ on $[0,1]$ which is perfect and nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The answer is given as follows, I will type until the step where I think it is wrong, or this step might be insightful as to what I do not understand in the answer. Here is goes:

The construction is similar to the construction of the Cantor set, which has all these attributes asked, but is measure $0$. But here we need the measure to be $\alpha$ so we take $\beta=1-\alpha$ and:

$$F_1=[0,1]\setminus \gamma_{11}\ \  ; \ \ \gamma_{11}=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\beta}{4},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\beta}{4}) \\ F_2=[0,1]\setminus \gamma_{21}\cup\gamma_{22} ; \gamma_{21}=(x_1-\frac{\beta}{8},x_1+\frac{\beta}{8});\gamma_{22}=(x_2-\frac{\beta}{8},x_2+\frac{\beta}{8})$$
Where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the in the middle of intervals $(0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\beta}{4})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\beta}{4},1)$ respectively.
$$..... \text{this pattern of making these sets goes on......} \\ 
 A=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\gamma_{nk}\\ m(A)=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}m(\gamma_{nk})=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n-1}\beta}{2^n2^{n-1}}$$
This last line makes no sense to me, from it one would conclude that $m(\gamma_{nk})=\frac{\beta}{2^{2n+1}}$ but I think it is $\frac{\beta}{2^{n}}? $ What am I not seeing, am I incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first interval you remove ($\gamma_{11}$) has measure $\frac{\beta}{2}$. The next two ($\gamma_{21}$ and $\gamma_{22}$), as you have written them, each have measure $\frac{\beta}{4}$. But then their combined measure $\frac{\beta}{2}$. This construction cannot be correct, for then you remove intervals of combined measure $\frac{\beta}{2}$ at each step. The total measure of the intervals you remove needs to decrease at each step (so that the total measure of the intervals you remove does not exceed $1$).

Instead you want the *total* measure of $\gamma_{n,1}, \dots, \gamma_{n,2^{n-1}}$ to be $\frac{\beta}{2^n}$. There are $2^{n-1}$ of these intervals, so if they have equal measure, that measure is $m(\gamma_{nk})=\frac{\beta}{2^n}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{\beta}{2^{2n-1}}$. So, for example, you should have instead:
$$\gamma_{21}=\left(x_1-\frac{\beta}{16},x_1+\frac{\beta}{16}\right);\gamma_{22}=\left(x_2-\frac{\beta}{16},x_2+\frac{\beta}{16}\right).$$
Them $m(\gamma_{21})=m(\gamma_{22})=\frac{1}{2^{2\cdot 2 -1}}$. This is consistent with the equation you wrote, which implies $m(\gamma_{nk})=\frac{1}{2^{2 n-1}}$ (not $\frac{1}{2^{2^ n +1}}$).

Answer (score 0):

In a similar spirit, you could also consider an open interval $(a_{m}, b_{m})$. Then take intervals of the form $(c_{m}, d_{m})$ with $c_{m}, d_{m} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and each of length at most $2^{-m}(1 - \alpha)$.

Then the set $E = [0, 1] \backslash \cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}(c_{m}, d_{m})$ is compact as it is a closed set in a compact set and its interior is empty since all the open intervals are removed and it has a length at most $\alpha$.